# How to make an object move towards another object in C# XNA

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, position, angle

I'm currently trying to make an object move towards another. I have this code so far to try and achieve it.

```
double angleRad = Math.Atan2(mdlPosition.Z+treeTransform.Translation.Z, mdlPosition.X-treeTransform.Translation.X);

enemyPos.X += (float)Math.Cos(angleRad) * 0.2f;
enemyPos.Z += (float)Math.Sin(angleRad) * 0.2f;
```

Whenever I move my player character, the object moves, but not towards the characters current position. How can I direct it towards current position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should act in this way. I suppose you want that the enemy will move toward the player.

```
Vector2 dir = player.Position - enemy.Position;
dir.Normalize();
```

Now you only have to do every cycle:

```
enemy.Position += dir * speed;
```

**EDIT**

To make the enemy face the player try calculate the angle of `dir` and set it as `rotation` parameter of your draw call. You should achieve this using `Math.Atan2(dir.Y, dir.X)`

Comment: do you know how i could get the enemy to face the player? i'm using matrices

Comment: Yap, this works for Vector3, too. To your second question, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: you may be able to answer my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520739/how-to-make-an-object-face-its-forward-vector, this time trying to face in the direction of a forward vector and not an object

Answer (score 0):

something from my head in pseudo code.

```
Direction = Enemy.Position - Player.Position
Direction.Normalize()
Enemy.Position += Direction * Speed
```

Comment: only thing wrong was that it was moving in the opposite direction of the player so i switched it to player.pos - enemy.pos. Thanks

Comment: do you know how i could get the enemy model to face the player?

Comment: try this: `angle = Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X)` using same normalized `Direction` ... but mr. pinckerman allready answer you :)