# How to make an object face its forward vector

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, rotation, angle

Similar to my recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518218/how-to-make-an-object-move-towards-another-object/20519135?noredirect=1#comment30677632_20519135) only this time I would like to move the object towards a vector and not another object.

```
Vector3 line = dalekList[i].direction;
float rotationDal = (float)(-Math.Atan2(dalekList[i].position.X, -dalekList[i].position.Z) / (2 * Math.PI));

Matrix dalekTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(GameConstants.DalekScalar) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationDal) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(dalekList[i].position);
```

So I would need to put the rotation (`rotationDal`) into the `CreateRotationY`, only I'm not sure how to calculate that angle.

Comment: should add the intended vector is its forward vector

Comment: What do you mean with "towards a vector"? You mean you want your object to "watch" in that direction?

Comment: yes so it constantly updates its rotation to "watch" the direction its facing

Comment: If the vector you mean is `dalekList[i].direction`, have you tried to use `Atan2` on it?

Comment: not yet, i tried with position for some reason, i'll give it a go now

Comment: if you want to put the answer down i'll tick it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vector you want to "watch" is `dalekList[i].direction`, you should try to use `Atan2` on it, instead of position.